# Unable to open dependencies file (Xcode 14)(Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift

Everytime I try to open up Xcode simulator I get this error

> error build: unable to open dependencies file
> (/Users/INSERTNAMEHERE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Musical-frliqdxsuhgvmmcypwrrrvihqtaa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Musical.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Musical.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.d)

I assume this is a problem with a simulator package of some sort, so how do I fix this.

Comment: Delete your derived data?

Comment: Try pressing `Cmd` + `Shift` + `K` to clean you build results and then build again.

Comment: @DarkDust, that worked! If you put it in the answers section it will be better.

Answer (score 1):

Once  clear DerivedData and check.

> `xCode preferences > location > DerivedData` click arrow and automatically open derivedData folder .  delete it and restart xCode.

Comment: Usually there's no need for this brute-force method. `Product > Clean Build Folder` does mostly the same, but for your current project only.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode sometimes has issues with cached derived files, which may become inconsistent. Seems to happen sometimes after switching a VCS (Git) branch, for example.

Clean the derived files for your current project by using the menu `Product > Clean Build Folder` or the corresponding keyboard shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then build again.